# How to get full tree hierarchy from table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with following structure:

```sql
create table crosses (a varchar, b varchar);
```

with sample data:

```sql
insert into crosses values ('1','A');
insert into crosses values ('1','B');
insert into crosses values ('2','A');
insert into crosses values ('2','C');
insert into crosses values ('3','C');
insert into crosses values ('3','D');
insert into crosses values ('4','E');
```

I want to get full graph of references like following:

```
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 C
3 C
3 D
```

I'm trying to achieve this using following query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT
    a,
    b,
    FALSE revertRef
  FROM
    crosses
  WHERE
    a = '1'

  UNION

  SELECT
    c.a,
    c.b,
    (NOT cte.revertRef) revertRef
  FROM
    cte
    INNER JOIN crosses c ON 
      (CASE WHEN cte.revertRef THEN c.a ELSE c.b END) = (CASE WHEN cte.revertRef THEN cte.a ELSE cte.b END)      
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE revertRef ORDER BY a;
```

When the table has a small amount of data, the query works fast, but in production, I have a table with more than 50 millions records, so query executes too long (about 10 hours). Does it exist some solution for this type of tasks?

Comment: Your sample output isn't a very good example being that it could almost be produced by `SELECT *` from your sample input and doesn't represent the need for a recursive query. The slow part of the query is almost certainly the `CASE` statements in the `WHERE` clause. The purpose of `revertRef` is unclear, can you clarify that a bit please?

Comment: Also, add the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result to the question please.

Comment: @JSpratt it's impossible for now to include an execution plan, because query didn't complete not once.

Comment: Haha true. Sorry bout that, silly me.

Comment: What are `a` and `b` in the crosses table or what is the relationship between `a` and `b`? Are they all nodes? Is the crosses table meant to represents edges between nodes? What makes record `'4', 'E'` an excluded record?

Comment: @JSpratt This task goes from the sphere of automobile spare parts. There are original spare parts (OEMs) and replacements for them. So I have a table, which contains this cross-records (let's assume that "a" is an OEM and "b" is a replacement). That's why I want to get a tree of crosses. Record 4-E is excluded because it doesn't have any references with other records.

Comment: @JSpratt There is some image explanation of how they are linked: https://imgur.com/a/bqnhJin

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my solution? If this doesn't work maybe explaining why could help me understand the need for a recursive solution. What I'm gathering is that `a` can be something like a tie rod end from OEM and a number of `b` could be from an aftermarket manufacturer. So what I think I'm confused by is why you need to look back from aftermarket to OEM. Are you looking for aftermarket parts that can replace many OEM part numbers?

Comment: You are right.
That's why in the example:
```1 A
1 B
2 A
2 C
3 C
3 D```

spare part ```1 A``` can be replaced by ```3 D``` and reverse.